# Selecting a 2d array position to add a value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am making a 2d array in VB, and i need help trying to figure out how to select a position in the 2d array which then has a value entered to it. I know how to loop through the array elements and adding values to it but this would be a quicker way if i just pick a position and have a value entered to it.

Thanks

Console.WriteLine("What position would like to enter a value:")
        userInput = Console.ReadLine

```
    Console.WriteLine(" Would you like to enter another 1 ?? (Y or N)")
    If (reply = "Y") Or (reply = "y") Then
        reply = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("What position would like to enter a value:")
        userInput = Console.ReadLine

    End If

    For row = 0 To cRow
        For column = 0 To cColumn
            If grid(row, column) = 0 Then
                Console.Write(Chr(32))
            Else
                Console.Write(Chr(42))
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need three pieces of information to add a value to your array, two coordinates (row, column) and the value. Assuming you have this information you would just do.

```
    Dim grid(2, 2) As String
    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim column As Integer = 0
    Dim value As String = "something"

    grid(row, column) = value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the position, you obviously have to ASK the user to provide it. And since this is user input, you MUST check if the stuff the user entered is something helpfull (rule 1: never trust users!)

```
Sub Main()

    Dim matrix(8, 8) As String

    Do
        ' get user input
        Console.Write("Enter coordinates in the form: 'x,y'")
        Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
        ' empty string=quit
        If input.Length = 0 Then Exit Do
        ' split on ',' character
        Dim spl = input.Split(","c)
        ' there must be exactly two values
        If spl.Count <> 2 Then Continue Do
        ' check if user entered two NUMBERS
        Dim x, y As Integer
        If Not Integer.TryParse(spl(0), x) Or Not Integer.TryParse(spl(1), y) Then Continue Do
        ' Validate x
        If x < 0 OrElse x > UBound(matrix, 1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("x must be 0..{0}", UBound(matrix, 1))
            Continue Do
        End If
        ' Validate y
        If y < 0 OrElse y > UBound(matrix, 2) Then
            Console.WriteLine("y must be 0..{0}", UBound(matrix, 2))
            Continue Do
        End If
        ' set value
        matrix(x, y) = "x"
        Console.WriteLine("Value saved")
    Loop

    ' output matrix
    For y = 0 To UBound(matrix, 2)
        For x = 0 To UBound(matrix, 1)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix(x, y)) Then
                Console.Write(".")
            Else
                Console.Write(matrix(x, y))
            End If
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```